# What is the .igGrid() method in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, igrid

I'm looking at Infragistic's code from a sample page and they have the following jQuery statement that is confusing me:

```
<table id="grid">
```

```
$("#grid").igGrid({ "caption" : "This is a caption for the grid"});
```

I know that `$("#grid")` is selecting the table element, but what is `.igGrid`? It looks like it's assigning an object (igGrid) that contains properties (?), but how? How is `.igGrid` not flagged as an error?

Comment: `igGrid` is the name of the jQuery method being called. It's non-standard so must have been explicitly included in your project. For your own reference, it's easy to create your own jQuery plugins: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: https://www.igniteui.com/help/iggrid-overview

Comment: Ah, it's a plugin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not assigning any object, it is converting your table to **DataGrid**.
**DataGrid**(part of Ignite UI) is a jQuery plug-in like any other plug-ins e.g. DataTable, Steps etc.
This will add additional customizable features to your table. Follow the [documentation here](https://www.igniteui.com/grid/overview).
There must be a reference to **Ignite UI** js in this page.

Comment: Ah, it's a plugin. Thank you.

Comment: _"It is not assigning any object"_ - Well, you do assign an object in this specific example, the settings (`{ "caption" : "This is a caption for the grid"}`)

Comment: We can say `Caption` is a property of DataGrid